# Is it possible to add the same instance of a child to a StackLayoutPanel multiple times?

Tags: java, gwt

I have the following problem .. I am using StackLayoutPanel and
when I try to add a child of the same instance of another stack will
not let me and I remove his head and child.

The question is how I can make my stack allows many children of the
same instance?

I tried to make a wrapper of the children by putting them in another
LayoutPanel, are all the heads, but it only added the last child ah
the last head.

Thank you very much!
Jero.

Widget stackLayoutPanel child header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what a StackLayoutPanel is, however you should be able to add "different" instances of a component to the panel.

However, a Component can only have a single parent. So therefore you can't add the same Component to multiple panels.

This is solve by using "models". For example you can't add the same text field to two different panels but you can create two text fields and then share the model:

```
JTextField tf1 = new JTextField();
JTextField tf2 = new JTextField( tf1.getDocument() );
```

Comment: Ah finally I wanted to share a single instance to use I had to modify the component myself and I made some additions that I needed for my case .. I leave class I did CustomStackLayoutPanel perhaps someone will will Be useful!


Big hug!
Jero.